# Need to execute a sql query with variables from a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

So I need to run my sql query in a foreach loop, but, say there are two variables in the foreach loop, the query only executes the iteration with the first variable twice, instead of executing both the first and the second variable.

My code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers = '$selected';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach($_POST['order-check'] as $check) 
    {
        $sql2 = "UPDATE order_table SET order_status = 'Processing', assigned_vendor = '$selectedvendor' WHERE order_id = '$check';";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        exit();
    }
}
else{
    echo "failed";
    exit();
}
```

Here, `$selected` is a POST variable from another page

Comment: You have `exit()` in there, so it will only run the loop once. You also only fetch one row in your select query, while you loop the `$_POST['order-check']` until the end (except you `exit` after the first iteration).

Comment: Your second query doesn't use anything from `$row`. Why are you doing it in the loop?

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question.

Comment: @Barmar should I just use `if($result)` ?

Comment: Never mind, I thought you were doing `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`.

Answer (score 1):

As Qirel mentioned, remove the "exit()" from your foreach statement. 
Also, please ensure you sanitize any POST or GET variables before inserting into the database :)

Your statement should look like this if you want to loop through all $_POST variables

```
  foreach($_POST['order-check'] as $check) 
        {
            $sql2 = "UPDATE order_table SET order_status = 'Processing', assigned_vendor = '$selectedvendor' WHERE order_id = '$check';";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            //exit();
        }
```